# Ошибка в Js с new Vue (). Как это исправить?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код с `new Vue()`, который не работает, почему не знаю. Объясните пожалуйста почему возникла и как исправить. Я работаю в VS Code. Сразу говорю, что это не мой код, я просто скачал его для своего сайта, чтобы попробовать.

Консоль в Google: `script.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined`

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      currentCardBackground: Math.floor(Math.random()* 25 + 1),
      cardName: "",
      //Code....
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вставьте `script.js` после `vue.js`.

```js
new Vue();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Простите, но я не понял. В html написать <script>new Vue();</script>            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>?

Comment: В Вашей странице есть тег `script` с `src=".../vue.js"`?

Comment: Я вставил и все заработало но в консоле каша. 'vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: mask

(found in <Anonymous>)'

Comment: @Андрей Мне сквозь монитор плохо видно Ваши код и консоль.